# Android camera2 Lens intrinsic calibration

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-hardware, android-camera2

I downloaded an Android camera2 [demo](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic), it ran well.

Now I want to get the intrinsic matrix of the camera by querying the [CameraCharacteristics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html#LENS_INTRINSIC_CALIBRATION).

My code is

```
private void setUpCameraOutputs(int width, int height) {
    Activity activity = getActivity();
    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        for (String cameraId : manager.getCameraIdList()) {
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics
                    = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
            float[] intrinsic = new float[5];
            intrinsic = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_INTRINSIC_CALIBRATION);
    //...... leave out the following part
        }
    }
```

The intrinsic is expected to be a 5-element array but `intrinsic = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_INTRINSIC_CALIBRATION)` returns null.

Comment: Does your device claim full support of camera2 API?

Comment: How to claim the support? I have already add `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" android:required="true" />` in the manifest.xml

Comment: Many devices today only have [crippled implementations](http://www.dpreview.com/forums/post/55600463) of camera2 API. There is nothing you can do about it, only choose one of the few devices that are ahead of the heard.

Answer (score 8):

The lens intrinsics are only guaranteed to be defined if the camera device supports the [DEPTH_OUTPUT capability](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata.html#REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES_DEPTH_OUTPUT).

As of right now, the depth extensions to the camera2 API are new, and not yet supported by basically any Android device.

Comment: After 5 years, it is still not working even for the phones supporting Depth_Output capability.

Comment: If you're seeing devices with DEPTH_OUTPUT that don't define lens intrinsics properly, it'd be great to know which ones.

Comment: @EddyTalvala I am getting null on Samsumg A50