# Android NDK using Camera API 2 to get Intrinsics

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-camera2

I am currently trying to get the camera Intrinsic Parameters from my Smartphone (ZenFone AR), but unfortunately the Camera Tag "ACAMERA_LENS_PARAMETERS" never seem to be set.

Do i have to pre-configure the camera device or is this not available for every phone using NDK?

Here the Callback i wrote to get the parameters according to the documentation.

```
static void myResultCallback(
    void* context, ACameraCaptureSession* session,
    ACaptureRequest* request, const ACameraMetadata* result){

    ACameraMetadata_const_entry entry;
    ACameraMetadata_getConstEntry(result, 
    ACAMERA_LENS_INTRINSIC_CALIBRATION, &entry);
    LOGI("Camera Intrinsics: %f ,%f , %f, %f, %f", entry.data.f[0], 
     entry.data.f[1],entry.data.f[2],entry.data.f[3],entry.data.f[4]);
};
```

I connected this callback to my CameraCaptureSession_captureCallbacks.
This seems to work, at least Logcat Returns that the camera intrinsics are  empty.

Additionally i get the error message:"E/ACameraMetadata: getConstEntry: cannot find metadata tag 524298"

Am i doing something terribly wrong or is it possible that the Intrinsics are not available?

Comment: If your device has a [legacy](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata.html#INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_LEGACY) camera, the [Native camera API](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/stable_apis.html#camera) is not supported.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to be the problem.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/34074191/192373. For ZenFone AR, you should use [the Tango API](https://developers.google.com/project-tango/apis/c/struct_tango_camera_intrinsics) instead of camera2 API.