# Camera 2 API - Intrinsic Camera Parameters

Tags: android, camera, camera-calibration, android-camera2

Is there a way to find out [Intrinsic Camera Parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_resectioning#Intrinsic_parameters) in Android using Camera 2 API without using OpenCV?

The official documentation has [CameraCharacteristics](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html#LENS_INTRINSIC_CALIBRATION) which contains intrinsic parameters. But using it always returns null as in [Referred Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34070557/android-camera2-lens-intrinsic-calibration). My device support level for Camera2 is logged as "LEGACY". Is that the reason for the intrinsic parameters being unavailable? What is the way to obtain them in such cases?

Answer (score 1):

Intrinsic camera parameters are not yet widely supported on Android devices.

Only devices that support the [DEPTH_OUTPUT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata#REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES_DEPTH_OUTPUT) capability are required to support them; in particular, LEGACY devices will never support them.
Devices without that capability may support lens calibration fields, but it's relatively unlikely right now.

In the upcoming Android P release, devices that support the new LOGICAL_MULTI_CAMERA capability will also have to support some lens calibration metadata, but that's only available in the P beta release right now.

Comment: So what are the device names those support Depth_output ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, From [opencv documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#details), You can make the camera intrinsic matrix yourself. camera intrinsic matrix is  a matrix that is made of focal length and principal point of an the image.

```
camera_matrix = [
                   [fx, 0, cx],
                   [0, fy, cy],
                   [0,  0, 1 ],
                ]
```

Where `fx` and `fy` are the focal length of the camera that you can get by [`getFocalLength`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters#getFocalLength()) method:

```
Camera.getParameters.GetFocalLength() : float
```

And `cx` and `cy` is the principal point that is taken the center of the image or the `[0, 0]` position of the image in pixels.

```
cx = image.width / 2;
cy = image.height / 2;
```

Comment: getFocalLength() returns the length in mm. So one must first convert to pixels before this

Comment: @GabiMe Can you please elaborate how one can do that?