# How can I find INTRINSIC MATRIX in android cameraX

Tags: android, android-camerax

I need INTRINSIC MATRIX data and show it to the user. how can I find it in android CameraX?

Comment: Have you seen: [Camera 2 API - Intrinsic Camera Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50442433/295004)

Comment: @MorrisonChang Yes, I seen it. but I don't know how can I get the preview width and height size. for cx and cy.

Comment: @MorrisonChang BAsed on  This link, i think i have to create custom list. fx and fy values get from   val cameraCapabilities =
                characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_INFO_AVAILABLE_FOCAL_LENGTHS). am i right?