# Android camera2 API intrinsics and the DEPTH_OUTPUT capability

Tags: android, android-camera2

Extracting intrinsic calibration parameters from an android device's camera using the camera2 API is known to be problematic.

However the guidance has been that if the phone supports the `DEPTH_OUTPUT` capability, it is guaranteed to also provide camera intrinsics (via `LENS_INTRINSIC_CALIBRATION`).

This is stated in the following sources:

- In [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34074191/19991657)
- In the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata#REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES_DEPTH_OUTPUT), where it is stated that:

> [The `DEPTH_OUTPUT`] capability requires the camera device to support the following:
>
> - This camera device, and all camera devices with the same `android.lens.facing`, will list the following calibration metadata entries in both `CameraCharacteristics` and `CaptureResult`:
>
>   - `android.lens.intrinsicCalibration`

Still, the Huawei P30 Pro claims to support the `DEPTH_OUTPUT` capability but ***does not*** provide any useful intrinsics (all intrinsic parameters are zero).

For what it's worth, the Huawei P30 Pro's support for the camera2 API is `INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_LIMITED`, but this should not matter, as neither of the sources cited above give any conditions on the device's camera2 API support level for extracting intrinsics.

Could anyone please help?

Comment: I'm not sure about the DEPTH_OUTPUT, but from my experience with Xiaomi/Huawei they are far from implementing the Camera2 spec.

Comment: @gioravered Many thanks for your insight -- yes, it looks like it. I'm forming the suspicion that the documentation's claim (DEPTH_OUTPUT guarantees intrinsics) holds only for devices with a certain support level and above. But this is not stated anywhere as far as I have read.