# Difference in the Availability of Camera Intrinsics via the Camera2 API Between Almost Identical Phones

Tags: android, google-play, android-camera2, camera-intrinsics

I am well are aware that not all phones yield camera intrinsics via the `camera2` API. However, I find it very puzzling that some phones yield intrinsics while other **almost identical** phones do not. E.g. the Samsung Galaxy S20 FE (SM-G780G) yields intrinsics via the `camera2` API, whereas the Samsung Galaxy S20 5G (SM-G981B) strangely does not.

This seems very strange, for the following reasons:

- The two phones are almost identical (by brand/manufacturer, model, even budget...).
- The two phones list identical system features related to the camera (e.g. they both have the `android.hardware.camera.level.full` feature, among many others).
- (If at all relevant) the two phones also list almost identical system features that don't have anything to do with the camera.

**Questions:**

- ***Why*** this difference in behavior between almost identical phones?
- ***Why*** does the `android.hardware.camera.level.full` feature ***not*** guarantee the availability of intrinsics? I mean, what does "full" mean here, anyway?
- ***How*** to prevent our app from showing in Google Play for those devices which do not yield intrinsics via the `camera2` API?

  - App filtering in Google Play works with system features. ***Which*** system feature(s) will conclusively determine whether intrinsics are available?

This confusion also opens even **more fundamental questions:**

- If one ***device*** of a model variant (e.g. a Samsung S20 FE SM-G780G device) yields intrinsics, does this mean that ***all*** devices of the ***same*** model variant (i.e. all Samsung S20 FE SM-G780G devices) are also guaranteed to yield intrinsics?
- If one variant of a model (e.g. Samsung S20 FE SM-G780***G***) yield intrinsics, does this mean that all other variants of the same model (e.g. Samsung S20 FE SM-G780***F***) are also guaranteed to yield intrinsics?

Has anyone had any similar experience? Maybe we are doing something wrong?

Many thanks in advance for any help you can give!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of hardware level `FULL` is [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata#INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_FULL).  It used to cover nearly everything the API supported, but since the definition cannot be changed after it is defined (for backwards compatibility reasons), there's a lot of stuff added in later API versions that is not covered by the `FULL` spec.

So for example, it doesn't mandate lens calibration information, which is only required for cameras that support either the [DEPTH_OUTPUT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata#REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES_DEPTH_OUTPUT) or [LOGICAL_MULTI_CAMERA](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata#REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES_LOGICAL_MULTI_CAMERA) capabilities.

Though any device can advertise them if it wants to, even if those capabilities aren't listed.

Those Samsungs both have two versions, one using a Qualcomm processor, and one using an Exynos processor. I suspect it's the SoC difference that makes a difference on whether the lens calibration fields are present.  Each SoC vendor provides a default camera implementation to the manufacturer, and I suspect one vendor has the calibration information present, and the other doesn't.  It's also possible one phone does have an additional feature in its default camera app that uses this information, and thus has it populated in the API.

So I wouldn't necessarily trust that every variant of the same phone has the same capabilities, unfortunately.

> How to prevent our app from showing in Google Play for those devices which do not yield intrinsics via the camera2 API?

Unfortunately, there's no system feature that covers this, so it's not possible to use Play Store filtering for camera intrinsics.

Comment: Thank you for your insights! Here are a few follow-ups before I close the question: (a) I understand that if a single device (of any certain phone variant) yields intrinsics, then **all** devices of the same variant are guaranteed to yield intrinsics. Is this true? (b) Could your observation about the SoC/processor (Qualcomm vs Exynos) be used as a rule? I.e. would phones with the same SoC (as the phone in the question) be somewhat certain to give intrinsics? (c) The Huawei P30 Pro claims both DEPTH_OUTPUT and LOGICAL_MULTI_CAMERA for one of its cameras but its intrinsics are all 0.0 -- why?

Comment: a) There are no official guarantees about that, though I'd generally expect it to be true.  b) Same  c) That's surprising, since it's not that old of a phone. There are compliance tests that aim to verify that the intrinsics are reasonable, so it's unexpected one would be that badly coded up.

Comment: Thanks again for your great responses! Btw part (c) of my comment above is also a separate question I posted some time ago. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73712728/android-camera2-api-intrinsics-and-the-depth-output-capability) is the question, if you would like to answer that one too.

Comment: I have a final follow-up (sorry to pester you again): Currently it feels like too many phones fail to give intrinsics via the camera2 API. From your experience, would you know if intrinsics via camera2 is something which we can count on in the future? Are there any plans for better support on this?

Comment: Accurate intrinsics require both per-device factory calibration (since every lens module is slightly different), and ideally ongoing dynamic calibration as the phone ages.  Those are both complex to do right, and expensive on a per-unit basis (the factory calibration bit).  So it's hard to mandate it across Android, when there are so many lower-price devices available.  But it's something that should become more reliable in the more premium devices at least.

Comment: Thank you @Eddy Talvala for all the help!